# Eclipse Dstore server

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee

I recently stumbled across Eclipse's Dstore server, couldn't understand what it really does from the articles on the net.
Can someone please tell me what is the use of Dstore server? Also, is it possible to develop server side code which could be accessed from client machine through Dstore server, like web requests are served by servlets via App server?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

RSE DStore (Remote System Explorer DataStore) is one of the protocols supported by the [Target Management project](http://www.eclipse.org/dsdp/tm/) (the others being [ssh or ftp](http://ikool.wordpress.com/2008/07/22/ssh-access-through-eclipse-rse/)).
Hence the use of a [DStore server](http://ikool.wordpress.com/2008/06/26/how-to-install-dstore-for-eclipse-rse-remote-system-explorer/), to give access to [remote file-system and remote processes](http://www.eclipse.org/dsdp/tm/tutorial/index.php).

[image: New Connection]

Introduced [late 2006](http://tmober.blogspot.com/2006/11/remote-system-explorer-10-is-released.html), you will find all the details and API in the [RSE DStore Developer Guide](http://help.eclipse.org/galileo/index.jsp?nav=/29):

> The DataStore communications framework is used to provide remote access and tooling for the Remote System Explorer.
>   It is a:
>
> - communications layer,
> - in-memory data repository and
> - a pluggable tooling framework.
>
> While Eclipse provides the ability for local tools to plug into the Eclipse workbench, DataStore provides the ability to integrate remote tools into the Remote System Explorer

[image: Eclipse Architecture]

Comment: Thanks VonC for your reply. I have one more question related to DStore server.
As you commented DStore is used to integrate remote tools into the RSE, does this mean we can integrate Unix script with Eclipse framework. Like can we have the functionality to run a script at remote Unix box when user click on an action button in Eclipse?
Appreciate your help.

Comment: @Gabriel: "functionality to run a script at remote Unix box when user click on an action button in Eclipse" That should be possible, yes, provided the system call (the script) is encapsulated in a Java "Miner" (see http://help.eclipse.org/galileo/topic/org.eclipse.dstore.doc.isv/guide/Miners.html). I have no concrete example to illustrate that, though, meaning a bit of exploration is needed here.